# Что не так с кодировкой при отправке GET запроса?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Делаю проект сервера для обмена данными в виде json. Тут встала загвоздка. Почему у меня не совпадает кодировка? Также было бы интересно, какие в этом коде у меня ошибки?

```
[{works: [titleOfWork: "РќР°Р·РІР°РЅРёРµ СЂР°Р±РѕС‚С‹ 1",cost: 0}],_id: "5f2e92e98d97391c7f4ea137",title: "Р“Р°Р·(РЎРђР—)"}]
```

Код роутера home.js

```js
const {Router} = require('express');
const Cars = require('../models/Car');
// const Work = require('../models/Works');
const router = Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('GET', '/', `status: ${res.statusCode}`);
    const cars = await Cars.find({});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(cars))
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const homeRoutes = require('./src/routes/home');

app.use(homeRoutes);

async function start() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cars', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });

        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('Server started in port: 3000');
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, new Date());
    }
}

start();
```

А это код модели Car.js

```js
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose');


const schema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    works: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
        // ref: 'Work'
    }
});

module.exports = model('Car', schema);
```

Comment: Вопрос был решен указанием вместо res.end(JSON.stringify(cars)) написал await res.json(cars); Я правильно сделал?

Comment: await то зачем?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Согласен. IDE на него ругалась.